# Unable to connect to Google Ads API with service account and the Python librairy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api

For a week now I have been crawling the web but haven't find any legit documentation to connect the python librairie for Ads API with Service Account.

I want to create a micro-service, server-to-server, so anything else apart service account as authentication is off-table.

On GCP, I was using oAuth2 but I had to manually refresh the tokens with https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ which isn't a viable solution.

What I have done so far :

1. I created a service account
2. generated a key to it in JSON and downloaded it.
3. Add all possible access to my service-account permissions, such as :

- Owner
- Security Reviewer
- Service Account Admin
- Service Account Key Admin
- Service Account Token Creator
- Service Account User

4 - Created my script to authenticate :

```
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

credentials = {
                "developer_token":  "xXxxxXxxxXxxXXXXxXxxX",
                "use_proto_plus":  true,
                "json_key_file_path":  "./path_to_json.json" ,
                "impersonated_email":  "gcp_and_ads_admin_email",
                "login_customer_id":  "XXXXXXXXXX"
            }

client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)
```

When I execute my script, this error follows :

`google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any  of the scopes requested.'})`

Does anyone know how I can find a tutorial or help me with this please ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a service account with the Google Ads API, you'll need a [Google Workspace domain](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts#prerequisites).

If you don't have one, I'd recommend to use the standard OAuth2 flow to obtain a refresh token of a user that has access to the Google Ads account. These tokens don't expire and can be exchanged for an access token which will authenticate your request.